# Parse output of command and store in variables

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to parse the output of the *mmls* command and store multiple values in variables using a BASH script.

Specifically, I need to store: **sector size** (512 in the example below), and **start values** (0,0,63,224910,240975 in the example below). Since the second set of values represent partitions, the number of values captured could vary.

```
mmls /mnt/E01Mnt/RAW/ewf1 
DOS Partition Table
Offset Sector: 0
Units are in 512-byte sectors

      Slot      Start        End          Length       Description
000:  Meta      0000000000   0000000000   0000000001   Primary Table (#0)
001:  -------   0000000000   0000000062   0000000063   Unallocated
002:  000:000   0000000063   0000224909   0000224847   NTFS / exFAT (0x07)
003:  000:001   0000224910   0000240974   0000016065   DOS FAT12 (0x01)
004:  -------   0000240975   0000250878   0000009904   Unallocated
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

```
$ awk '/^Units/{print $4+0} /^[0-9]/{print $3+0}' file
512
0
0
63
224910
240975
```

Try to solve the rest yourself and then let us know if you have questions.

Explanation: `file` is a file containing your sample input. You can replace `awk '{script}' file` with `command | awk '{script}'` if you're input is coming from the output of some command rather then being stored in a file.

`^` is the universal regexp metacharacter for `start of string` while `/.../` in awk means "find this regexp". So the above is looking for lines that start with the text shown (i.e. `Units` or digits) and then printing the 4th or 3rd space-separated field after adding zero to it to remove any trailing non-digits or leading zeros. `man awk`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Would you mind providing a basic explanation of what you're doing here? What is the "/^" for? How about $4? Also, what is "file" in your code?

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a bit of `awk` to start with.

```
values=( $(mmls /mnt/E01Mnt/RAW/ewf1 | awk '
/^Units are in/{match($4,/^[[:digit:]]+/,ss); print ss[0]}
NR>6{print $4}'
) )
```

Now you have a values array which contains both the sector size(first element) and the start values(subsequent elements) . We could do some array manipulation to separate individual elements.

```
secsize=${values[0]} # size of sector

declare -a sv # sv for start values

for((i=1;i<${#values[@]};i++))
do
 sv+=( ${values[i]} )
done
echo "${sv[@]}" # print start values
unset values # You don't need values anymore.
```

<sub>**Note:** Requires GNU awk.</sub>